# Recursive xslt function for adding ul list hierarchy needs fixing

Tags: xslt

I'm trying a recursive function to nest flat elements by their outline level, but the function strips text from some of the elements. Otherwise I'm close to this working as the elements are being properly nested by outline level.

This is the source XML. The goal is to nest higher outline elements inside the lower.

```
<article>
    <h3 class="icon component">
        <img src="images/component.png" alt="component" class="bullet"/>
    <span>Component: Forms</span>
    </h3>
    <p class="url details" data-outline="4">Sample: <a href="https://foo.com">foo.com</a></p>
    <p class="details" data-outline="4">Start line: 540</p>
    <p class="details" data-outline="4">End line: 700</p>
    <p class="details" data-outline="4">Foo</p>
    <li class="icon task" data-outline="4">
        <img src="images/task.png" alt="task" class="bullet"/>
        <p class="gist">Foo (Sev 3) (H48) </p>
    </li>
    <img src="images/image37.png" class="details" alt="Foo" data-outline="5"/>
    <p class="details" data-outline="5">Foo foo</p>
    <p class="details" data-outline="5">Foo foo</p>
    <li class="icon task" data-outline="4">
        <img src="images/task.png" alt="task" class="bullet"/>
        <p class="gist">Foo <code>foo</code> (Sev 3) (G83)</p>
    </li>
   <img src="images/image38.png" class="details" alt="" data-outline="5"/>
    <p class="caption details" data-outline="5">Screenshot: Foo foo</p>
    <li class="icon task" data-outline="5">
        <img src="images/task.png" alt="task" class="bullet"/>
        <p class="gist">foo foo (Sev 2) (2.4.6, G131)</p>
    </li>
    <p class="details" data-outline="6">Foo foo</p>
</article>
```

This is the function:

```
<xsl:function name="fpp:group" as="node()*">
    <xsl:param name="elements" as="element()*"/>
    <xsl:param name="outline" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$elements" group-starting-with="*[@data-outline[.=$outline]]">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="self::*[@data-outline[.=$outline]]">
                <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="copy"/>
                    <xsl:sequence select="fpp:group(current-group() except ., $outline + 1)"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="copy"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:function>
```

Here's how I call it:

```
<xsl:template match="article[li[matches(@class,'icon')]]" mode="step06">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="hierarchy" select="fpp:group(*, 4)"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$hierarchy" mode="copy"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This is the current output, properly nested but note that the moved p.details elements are missing their text() string:

```
<article>
    <h3 class="icon component">
        <img src="images/component.png" alt="component" class="bullet"/>
        <span>Component: Forms</span>
    </h3>
    <p class="url details" data-outline="4">
        <a href="https:foo.com">foo.com</a>
    </p>
    <p class="details" data-outline="4"/>
    <p class="details" data-outline="4"/>
    <p class="details" data-outline="4"/>
    <li class="icon task" data-outline="4">
        <img src="images/task.png" alt="task" class="bullet"/>
            <p class="gist">Foo (Sev 3) (H48) </p>
            <img src="images/image37.png" class="details" alt="Foo" data-outline="5"/>
            <p class="details" data-outline="5"/>
            <p class="details" data-outline="5"/>
    </li>
    <li class="icon task" data-outline="4">
        <img src="images/task.png" alt="task" class="bullet"/>
        <p class="gist">Foo <code>foo</code> (Sev 3) (G83)</p>
        <img src="images/image38.png" class="details" alt="" data-outline="5"/>
        <p class="caption details" data-outline="5"/>
        <li class="icon task" data-outline="5">
            <img src="images/task.png" alt="task" class="bullet"/>
            <p class="gist">Foo foo (Sev 2) (2.4.6, G131)</p>
            <p class="details" data-outline="6"/>
        </li>
    </li>
</article>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

I guess `<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="copy"/>` should be `<xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"/>` (or spelled out `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="copy"/>`).

Comment: Bless you and all those who depend on you. How many years will I have to spend on XSLT before that distinction makes sense to me? LOL. I've been at it for almost three years, very clumsily at first, but I'd never have figured that out alone. Thanks!